# Parent repo not detecting commits in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I make a change in the submodule and commit it, come back to the parent repo and on checking `git status`, expect it to say there are changes in the submodule, but nothing is listed. The parent repo doesn't point to the latest commit of the submodule either.

Comment: I believe this is intended behaviour. What is the point of having a submodule, if changes to it would always affect the parent repository?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The changes in the submodule are committed already. Shouldn't the parent repo then be able to find those commits so it can point to it?

Comment: Can you show us the exact sequence of steps you performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have intermittently experienced the issue you describe and the following commands have worked for me

```
git rm --cached path/to/submodule
git restore --staged path/to/submodule
```

`git status` should now show the new commit in the submodule

Comment: Thank you. I will try this the next time it happens and accept your answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `git status` to see submodule status :

```
git config status.submoduleSummary true
```